# How to migrate `ResponseTemplateTransformer(false)` into WireMock version 3 - Java code

Tags: wiremock

Being on WireMock version 2, I had the following snippet in some test code, which has been meant to instantiate the WireMockConfig object:

`com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig().dynamicPort().extensions(new ResponseTemplateTransformer(false))`

The idea has been not to have any specific response transformations.

After upgrading WireMock dependency to version 3, I realised the constructor on class `ResponseTemplateTransformer` which has been accepting only a boolean, has been disappeared. Looks like there is no good migration guide available online or I did not find it. So I will post what I did to hopefully save some one's time.

Answer (score 2):

So the answer to me was:

In order to have **no** response transformations active, do not make yourself tired searching for a new constructor equivalent to `ResponseTemplateTransformer(false)`.

**Just ignore calling the `extensions` builder-method** on `WireMockConfiguration` for passing the ResponseTemplateTransformer. You do not need a Transformer here:

`com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig().dynamicPort();`

I hope I'm not missing something here as I'm not that much into WireMock.

Comment: This is correct - local response templating is now on by default. If you want to switch it on globally you can add .globalTemplating(true) and if you want to disable it entirely .templatingEnabled(false)